# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ckeditor_uploader' in django

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

I'm trying to integrate a ckeditor in my django blog application. I followed all the instructions in the github page of django-ckeditor precisely.
i.e. installed, added to installed apps, added in urls, collected staticfiles, configured settings in settings.py and imported ckeditor.fields in models whenever necessary. When I try to make migration or run, I get this error as below:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/kush/projects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kush/projects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/kush/projects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/home/kush/projects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/home/kush/projects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kush/projects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/kush/projects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/kush/projects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/home/kush/projects/venv/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ckeditor_uploader'
```

I cant seem to figure out whats wrong here. Anyone here been with a similar issue?? Or just could show me some light here..

Answer (score 12):

I have same problem like this and just upgrade ckeditor with command:

```
pip install django-ckeditor --upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem but i had been solved this by adding this below  two line  in models.py file

```
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is generally occur when you dont have proper installation of module.
If you are getting this error using Virtual Environment or global  just try installing below module :

```
pip install django-ckeditor
```

if not then

```
pip install ckeditor
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `ckeditor` and `ckeditor_uploader` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`

Answer (score 0):

I have already done @Nikkey's suggestions but it sill was not working. I had django-ckeditor 3.6 version. I updated ckeditor as 5.9 version as manually. The problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and fixed it by including the path in the urls file with.

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("ckeditor/", include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')), # <-- here
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```