# My django project doesn't want to be deployed on heroku

Tags: python, django

I want to push my django project on heroku, I did all the steps from the tutorial, and I got an error `ModuleNotFoundError: there is no module called 'ckeditor'`
I tried to solve this problem by doing all the steps in this stackoverflow post - [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ckeditor_uploader' in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57545054/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-ckeditor-uploader-in-django) but that didn't work for me.
This is mine settings.py - > https://codeshare.io/Jb786X

This is my Traceback

```
(venvecosite) (base) cristian@FInch:~/Desktop/GreatEcology my project/ecosite/ecowebsite$ git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 1716, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1716/1716), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (1685/1685), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1716/1716), 46.84 MiB | 6.84 MiB/s, done.
Total 1716 (delta 174), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Using Python version specified in runtime.txt
remote:  !     Python has released a security update! Please consider upgrading to python-3.8.11
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Installing python-3.8.5
remote: -----> Installing pip 20.2.4, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.36.2
remote: -----> Installing dependencies with Pipenv 2020.11.15
remote:        Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (180c80)...
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
remote:            main()
remote:          File "manage.py", line 18, in main
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
remote:            django.setup()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
remote:            apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
remote:            app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 224, in create
remote:            import_module(entry)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
remote:            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
remote:        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ckeditor'
remote: 
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote: 
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote: 
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote: 
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: e1f2829e026243df3b14edd336ce0a60207c67b6
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version e1f2829e026243df3b14edd336ce0a60207c67b6
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to ecowebsite3.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/ecowebsite3.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/ecowebsite3.git'
```

Comment: check if `ckeditor` is in your `requirements.txt` file.

Comment: I am running into this exact same error and tried all the solutions in the linked post you provided. In my case, `requirements.txt` contains `django-ckeditor==6.2.0` so that doesn't seem to be the issue (but maybe I am missing something). Additionally, `ckeditor` and `ckeditor_uploader` were added to the `INSTALLED_APPS` of `settings.py`. I have been searching for an answer for this problem for about a month so I'm adding a bounty. Please let me know if there are any updates, this is the last step between the deployment of my website!

Comment: Heroku looks like it's installing requirements with Pipenv, not requirements.txt. Do you have a Pipfile? Does it contain ckeditor?

Answer (score 0):

My app was successfully deployed to Heroku thanks to jastr!

The issue was that my `Pipenv` and `Pipfile.lock` files were outdated (they didn't include django-ckeditor). I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67899118/how-to-update-piplock-file) and **deleted my pipenv and pipfile.lock files** from my local and pushed those changes to github. After deleting these files, Heroku was forced to install the packages listed in the `requirements.txt` file.